# How to call different router based on some value?

Tags: node.js, express

I had my routes being included like this until now:

```
router.use('/groups', require('./routes/system/groups'));
```

Is it possible to put function on the second parameter and to make something like this:

```
router.use('/sustav/groups', function(req, res){
        switch (req.user.role){ // role I have in user already

        case "admin": {
            return require('./routes/system/admin/groups');
        }

        case "user": {
            return require('./routes/system/user/groups');
        }

    }
});
```

Like this I would be able to separate controllers depending user role.

Comment: Why not have an `/admin/` route prefix for admins only?

Comment: Doesn't it look rather dirty?

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use('/sustav/groups', require('./routes/system/admin/groups'));
app.use('/sustav/groups', require('./routes/system/user/groups'));
```

**./routes/system/admin/groups**

```
...
if(req.user.role != 'admin') {
  return next();
}
...
```

**./routes/system/user/groups**

```
...
if(req.user.role != 'user') {
  return next();
}
...
```

Comment: I've tried this already :). It doesn't work, because req is not defined. Neither if you put it inside of closure arguments, because you're not getting them from anywhere.

Comment: Bleh, I'm an idiot. My test wasn't using `req` object and I didn't even think of it.

Comment: Yea, I've had a lot of problems with this and still can't find elegant solution for it.

Comment: This seems like fair solution! I'll check it out, a bit later, I'm just solving something.